# Neat way to define __all__?

Tags: python, import, package

Hi I'm building my own package and I have a question on __all__.
Are there any neat way to define __all__, other than explicitly typing each and every function in the module?
I find it very tedious...

I'm trying to make some code which wraps on frequently used libraries such as `numpy`, `pytorch`, `os`. The problem is, the libraries I used to create my modules also gets imported when I import my package.
**I want to import every function / class that I defined**, but I don't want the third-party libraries that I used in the process to get imported.
I use `from .submodule import *` in my `__init__.py` so that I can access my functions inside the submodule directly. (Just like we can access functions directly from the top package like `np.sum()`, `torch.sum()` )
My submodule has a lot of functions, and I want to import all of them to `__init__.py`, except for the third-party packages that I used.

I see that __all__ defines what to import when `from package import *` is called.
For example,

**utils.py**

```
__all__ = ['a']
def a():
    pass
def b():
    pass
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .utils import *
```

and

> >>> import package
> >>> package.a()
> None
> >>> package.b()
> NameError: 'package.b' is not defined

#### What I want is something like

```
__all__ = Some_neat_fancy_method()
```

I tried locals() and dir(), but got lost along the way.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can just *omit* `__all__` if you want to include everything

Comment: using * to import is the wrong practice. I suggest yout import by name, you can use `__all__` in `__init__` file and define which packages you want to make avaiable

Comment: I see how everyone got confused. I added more explanation. I'm building a package on top of other third-party libaries, and the problem is, they also get imported. I want to import every function / class that I defined, but I don't want the third-party libraries that I used in the process to get imported.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, the whole point of `__all__` is to explicitly specify what gets exposed to star-imports. By default everything is. If you really want to specify what *doesn't* get exposed instead, you can do a little trick and include all modules in `__all__` and then remove the ones you want to exclude.

For example:

```py
def _exclude(exclusions: list) -> list:
    import types

    # add everything as long as it's not a module and not prefixed with _
    functions = [name for name, function in globals().items()
                 if not (name.startswith('_') or isinstance(function, types.ModuleType))]

    # remove the exclusions from the functions
    for exclusion in exclusions:
        if exclusion in functions:
            functions.remove(exclusion)

    del types  # deleting types from scope, introduced from the import
    return functions


# the _ prefix is important, to not add these to the __all__
_exclusions = ["function1", "function2"]
__all__ = _exclude(_exclusions)
```

You can of course repurpose this to simply include everything that's not a function or prefixed with `_` but it serves little use since everything is included in star-imports if you don't specify the `__all__`, so I thought it was better to include the `exclusion` idea. This way you can simply tell it to exclude specific functions.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any neat way to define **all**, other than explicitly typing each and every function in the module?

Not built-in no. But defining `__all__` by hand is basically the entire point, if you want to include everything in `__all__` you can just do nothing at all:

> If `__all__` is not defined, the statement `from sound.effects import *` [...] ensures that the package sound.effects has been imported (possibly running any initialization code in `__init__.py`) and then imports whatever names are defined in the package.

The *entire point* of `__all__` is to restricts what gets "exported" by star-imports. There's no real way for Python to know that except by having you tell it, for each symbol, whether it should be there or not.

Answer (score 0):

One easy workaround is to alias all of your imports with a leading underscore. Anything with a leading underscore is excluded from `from x import *` style imports.

```
import numpy as _np
import pandas as _pd

def my_fn():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define a decorator named "export" and decorate the functions, classes, etc. that I want to add to **all**. The decorator adds the item to a list of "exports" and and then

**all** = exports